# Stratio cassandra-lucene-index plugin + BoundStatements

Tags: java, cassandra, lucene, stratio, cassandra-lucene-index

I just installed the Stratio [cassandra-lucene-index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) Cassandra plugin.

Is it possible to use the Stratio cassandra-lucene-index via BoundStatements somehow ?
Or 
Using the [Builder](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.3/doc/documentation.rst#all-search) is the closest as it can get ?

The reason I am asking is because I and looking to make my existing DAO layer, that is 100% based on BoundStatements, to use the Stratio cassandra-lucene-index and would like to continue using BoundStatements for many reasons: clarity, security and overall coding standardization within my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most [documentation examples](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.3/doc/documentation.rst#all-search) where recently updated to show how to search using `BoundStatements` and the `Builder` together.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I found a example within the [cassandra-lucene-index](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) test source code  [CassandraUtils.java](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.3/testsAT/src/test/java/com/stratio/cassandra/lucene/testsAT/util/CassandraUtils.java)

```
    public List<Row> searchWithPreparedStatement(Search search) {
            String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE expr(%s,?) LIMIT %d", qualifiedTable, index, LIMIT);
            final PreparedStatement stmt = CassandraConnection.session.prepare(query);
            BoundStatement b = stmt.bind();
            b.setString(0, search.build());
            return execute(b).all();
    }
```